# Multistep module not works for User Edit form (Edit Profile)

Tags: users, forms

The Multistep module works well for nodes in content types, like Article, Page, etc.

But when I tried to use Multistep for Account fields, it failed. I cannot find anything about "User form" in Structure->Block (while other content types Multistep form will be shown here).

How could I make the "Edit Profile" form as multi-step?

Answer (score 0):

Never used this module, but it seems that it could do what you need

https://drupal.org/project/step

It can be used both with deafult drupal registration system or with Profile2 module, however mind that it is still in dev version.

Cheers